# How to create GPX for IOS Simulator with Altitude and Court

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, gpx

How can I (or can I) create a GPX file that will run on the IOS simulator and provide course and altitude information?

I have added  tags in the hope they might give altitude but no joy there.

The larger issues I am having in dealing with the simulation of locations include:
1. The GPX documentation gives no semantic information; 
2. The I am unaware of any documentation on how the IOS simulator responds to GPX files; 
3. Many of the links to sites from this board for creating GPX files seem to create files with  tags that the IOS simulator seems to ignore.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to simulate the location of the device itself so that you can test location services code in your app?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359093/795339) describes the basics of simulating location—you create `wpt` elements in a GPX file. I tried adding `ele` child elements under some waypoints to simulate elevation changes, but my CLLocationManagerDelegate just reports 0 as the altitude. So I'm not sure if it's possible to simulate altitude or course.

Comment: After 2 years, still there no answer for this question ? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Adding _elevation_ tag don't seems to work for me but it's the GPX way of doing it so I guess that Apple still doesn't allow Simulator to work with it, here is the XML spec: http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_ptType

Comment: Please file radars asking for these changes. You can give me the radar numbers and I'll see if I can follow up.

Comment: I can confirm that as of 10/25/2018, this is still a limitation of the XCode simulator.  In my case I am trying to simulate a flight path, so being able to include elevation is essential.  I ended up creating my of mock layer that took as input json waypoints.