# CLLocationManagerDelegate Method Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, info.plist, mkuserlocation

I am coding in Swift and I want to use the user's location in my app. I have already added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to `Info.plist` and have properly configured them. I have also added CoreLocation.framework and imported it in the ViewController. I am also using `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in my class definition. I have implemented the method `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and this works when the user chooses to allow for their location to be given to the app. I have printed out text to console when this happens to make sure. However, when I call the method `didUpdateLocations` from this method right after printing to the console, the method does not run and nothing new is printed to console. I have made sure to include a print command in the `didUpdateLocations` method just to make sure of this. This is the code for one of the methods:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        print("permission granted")
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        print(status)
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the method, `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` is called and it is supposed to start doing that. Here is the code for this method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
}
```

However, once I press Allow in my app when it asks me, it doesn't print anything to the console besides "permission granted", which was called in the first method. How do I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Well, actually I just fixed the problem by simulating movement in the simulator phone. You just have to click Debug, hover over Location, and pick a form of movement!

Comment: are  you using the simulator?

Comment: Try simulating movement (presuming you're using the simulator) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359093/4475605

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Wow, how clueless can I be, it worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Should I post the answer in the question, or is it just too obvious?

Comment: it happens to all of us :) Most of time I  use the Apple location (Debug->Location->Apple) before I  can use the Custom Location. must be some simulator bug :)

Comment: You should definitely post an answer if you figured it out. You posted everything you'd tried, it was correct, and you were a nanometer away from the finish line.

Comment: OK thanks did that